# Django CMS Link - AttributeError 'Page' object has no attribute 'site'

Tags: django-cms, django-sites, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am able to add link through djagnocms_link. But when I double click on that link for edit It throws me this error - *[AttributeError 'Page' object has no attribute 'site']* inside ckeditor.
And interestingly it's only happens when I try to add link inside **Content**, but not in static **Footer**
Is there anyway to solve this problem? Or a better way to add links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug djangocms-link 2.6.0, upgrading to 2.6.1 helps.

The issue on github - https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/issues/183